# Show question tags when reviewing reopen votes

Tags: feature-request, tags, vote-to-reopen

I'm reviewing reopen votes, but half the time I can't tell what language the code is in and have to open in question in another tab, and it is pretty annoying. Example:

[image: question edit to review with no tags]

(link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043294/why-does-my-program-not-use-all-of-my-internet))

Seeing the tags would be super helpful to know what the question is about. Can they be added?

Comment: There are two big buttons on top (you didn't show them in screenshot), one shows complete question with tags.

Comment: I've never noticed that it's not present on all reviews: it all depends on which of those tab buttons are actually available. The UI seems to favour to go to a revision view which hides the tags. Not the most friendly UI design to be honest.

Comment: I always open the original question, because I also want to see if the edit was done by the OP, if any comment indicates that the OP disagrees with a duplicate and so on. Many reaons to see the original question for better judgement.

Comment: Maybe you could link to the review instead of the post?

Comment: I can see tags just fine - https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/27213984 (below the post, same as a regular question on the desktop site). I'm not exactly sure what you are proposing - add them to the top (or both), maybe fix it in some browser/views... anything else? So far I don't see need for this feature as it is already there...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's one review. Go through a few of them. You'll see that the situation changes from review to review. The first one in my queue today was this one which does not show the tags by default, because it opens the view in a revision tab: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/27243297

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, which brought me here to this meta post.  The answer is in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401502#comment798380_401502):

> There are two big buttons on top (you didn't show them in screenshot), one shows complete question with tags.

For a question in my queue I see three different views that can be selected: "Question (revised)", "Revision", and "Duplicate".

By default, the "Revision" option was selected.  Switching to the "Question (revised)" option shows the tags.  However, the tags are shown at the bottom of the question, so unless it's a particularly short question, you'll still have to scroll to see the tags.

Personally, I'd want the tags to always be shown, and to be shown up by the title of the question to be reviewed.  It's important context to me as a reviewer, since I'm much less likely to be able to reasonably cast a reopen vote on a topic I'm unfamiliar with.  I also have less interest in reviewing those questions, so I want to be able to quickly identify them skip past them.

Here's an example, with my browser zoomed as small as it lets me which barely gives enough room to show the tags at the bottom:

[image: review queue question with "Question (revised)" option selected, showing tags at the bottom]